# How to add an object to a list in Firebase realtime database without downloading the entire list beforehand?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

I am using [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) and I have a list of elements called `usernames`.

[image]

The usernames contain a `key: value` `(username: userid)`. Is there a way to add an item to the list without that the client downloads the entire username list?

For example, I am using `db.list(..)` but I can't find an info whether Firebase downloads all usernames before appending my data.

| method |  |
| --- | --- |
| `push(value: T)` | Creates a new record on the list, using the Realtime Database's push-ids. |
| `update(keyRefOrSnap: string, value: T)` | Firebase | Updates an existing item in the array. Accepts a key, database reference, or an unwrapped snapshot. |

https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md#api-summary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a direct reference to that username node and set the UID:

```js
firebase.database().ref('usernames/' + username).set(userUID)
```

Comment: That was it! Thanks a lot!